# When I add a Form{} element to view below the NavigationView, it creates a separate preview for that form, instead of putting both on one screen

Tags: swift, xcode, preview

Im wondering why the form element appears on a second preview canvas rather than under the List in the body View

Any suggestions appreciated :)

```
@State var showEmail = false

var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView{
        List(contacts) { contact in
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(contact: contact)) {
                ContactRow(showEmail: $showEmail, contact: contact)
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
        .navigationTitle("Contacts")
        
        Form {
            Toggle("Show Email", isOn: $showEmail)
            .onChange(of: showEmail) { newValue in
                showEmail.toggle()
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your preview struct.

Comment: @burnsi Its a standard preview struct housing ContentView().

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Try rendering the list rows with a `ForEach` instead and moving any controls that would have been in the form to their own section in the list.

You could try this:

```
@State var showEmail = false

var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView{
        List {
            ForEach(contacts) { contact in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(contact: contact)) {
                    ContactRow(showEmail: $showEmail, contact: contact)
                }
            }
            
            Section {
                Toggle("Show Email", isOn: $showEmail)
                .onChange(of: showEmail) { newValue in
                    showEmail.toggle()
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
        .navigationTitle("Contacts")
            
        }
    }
}
```